# How to use tee command with echo as per below requirement?

Tags: shell-script, echo, tee

Appending a variable which contains the `tee` command and log file name, not getting the expected result, since `echo` is printing the variable content.

Below is the file content, actual output and expected result.

Content of shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

log="2>&1 | tee -a report.txt"

echo ""
echo '***************-:START OF THE REPORT:-***********' $log
```

After running the script.

```
console op:
***************-:START OF THE REPORT:-*********** 2>&1 | tee -a report.txt
```

expected-

```
console op:
***************-:START OF THE REPORT:-***********

report.txt file content:
***************-:START OF THE REPORT:-***********
```

Also note that ,variable `$log` should contain both the `tee` command and file name, since I don't want to hard code the `tee` command at end of each echo command.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm assuming you would like to use this unusual way of tagging the actual pipe and `tee` onto the end of the log message because you don't want to have to pipe every `echo`?

Well, you can do it this way too:

```
logfile='report.txt'

log () {
    if [ -z "$1" ]; then
        cat
    else
        printf '%s\n' "$@" 
    fi | tee -a "$logfile"
}

log "some message"
log "some other message"
log "multi" "line" "output"

{
    cat <<LETTER
Dear Sir,

It has come to my attention, that a whole slew of things may be
collected and sent to the same destination, just by using a single
pipe. Just use { ... } | destination

Sincerely, $LOGNAME
LETTER

    cat <<THE_PS
PS.
Here's the output of "ls -l":
THE_PS

    ls -l

    echo "LOL"

} | log
```

That is, wrap the awkward `tee` command in a simple shell function whose name is easy to type and just pipe the output to it.

In this example, the `log` function uses `printf` to output the data given on its command line, or switches to reading from standard input if these was no command line arguments.

You could even use

```
./your_original_script_without_special_logging 2>&1 | log
```

Comment: How about commands like "mount" which gives multiple line output, which I want to print on console as well as log the output in a log file.

Comment: @PrashantBJ See my example.  `mount | log`.

Answer (score 1):

They way your are using the

```
echo '***************-:START OF THE REPORT:-***********' $log
```

line just echoes the content of `$log` to the command line, not acting as if you would enter that line in a console.

To make the line act as you expect you can or use `eval`.

```
eval echo '***************-:START OF THE REPORT:-***********' $log
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas ,your eval command input works fine.

Tried your input "$(echo $log)", is not working and its just printing the variable content.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Updated my answer. But to be honest, I would choose the answer from Kusalananda in your case.

Answer (score -1):

You should actually use a function masking the command `echo` for this:

```
echo ()
{
    builtin echo "$@" | tee -a report.txt
}
```

Then you can do:

```
echo ""
echo '***************-:START OF THE REPORT:-***********'
```

Without having to hardcode `tee` or anything else at the end of `echo` commands.

Comment: I'd recommend to name the function as `log` or similar, so you can still use the usual `echo` command when you don't want its output to be logged.

Comment: @nxnev there's always `builtin echo` if you want to override the function.

Comment: I agree, we should provide valuable examples, not ones, that override normal command, and thus as such this is not "exemplary" suggestion. Please don't leave it here for future readers.

Comment: @Linux well, I disagree. Overriding builtins is perfectly valid given certain usecases.